# How to include the response of a method defined in a controller into jbuilder view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a method defined in the controller like this.

```
def index
end
def show
end
def new
end
def edit
end
def create
end
def findsomething
    #do something using params and store it into an instance variable
    return @thatvariable
end
```

I want to include this response into the show.jbuilder file. How Can I do that?

Comment: Have you read the Jbuilder documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use something like this in show.json.jbuilder to do that.

```
json.findsomething(@thatvariable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Every instance variable is available in the views, so no need in the `return` keyword.

[Here is the railscast that will help](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=asciicast)

**Update**

In your controller action you may specify what view to render:

`render "show.json.jbuilder"`

So the overall code will be as follows:

```
def findsomething
    #do something using params and store it into an instance variable
    @thatvariable
    render "show.json.jbuilder"
end
```

You may read the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) for further information.

You may specify the way to you view you wish to renders and to which all the instance variables from controller#action will be available in different ways:

```
render :edit
render action: :edit
render "edit"
render "edit.html.erb"
render action: "edit"
render action: "edit.html.erb"
render "books/edit"
render "books/edit.html.erb"
render template: "books/edit"
render template: "books/edit.html.erb"
render "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit"
render "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb"
render file: "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit"
render file: "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb"
```

Comment: I was trying it like this `json.findsomething @thatvariable` in `show.jbuilder`. But that return as `null`.

Comment: Have you removed the `return` keyword from the controller?

Comment: Is you view called `findsomething.json.jbuilder` ?

Comment: yes, I removed that return.
I have controller which I created using scaffold, I have added the method in that controller file. I'm displaying that data through `jbuilder`. The controller contains the normal controller actions, this is the additional method which is added by me. Is that the right place to add that method? I have to do that in controller, because I have to access the `:params` in that method.

Comment: By convention the controller will pass data to the view with same name. Have you created the view?

Comment: @user121212 zmii is saying that since the controller method name is `findsomething` that it expects the view to be named `findsomething.json.jbuilder`. It is possible to re-use the template for the `show` method if you wanted to go that route.